# How to disable Segmented control in Android?

Tags: android, segmentedcontrol

Can any one please tell me, how to disable segmentedcontrol in android.
I have been using Foursquared library.

The link for [library](http://ttlnews.blogspot.in/2011/09/segmented-button-control-in-android.html) is given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing for that.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SegmentedButton
    android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    />

<Layout
    android:id="@+id/transperent_fragment"
    android:name="com.test.transperentFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/body_texture"
    android:alpha="0.2"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps you..:)